# *Python Too many if-statements are executing

Tags: python

I'm currently testing my skill by making a "rock paper scissors" game. I ran into a problem.

Some of the code: (I know it's kind of a lot for a problem, but look towards the end where most serval similar statements are and where # Win and # Lose also appear.)

```py
import random
computerScore = 0
Score = 0
print("> Type \"help\" for help. <")
print("---")
print("Loading Rock Paper Scissors...")
while True:
    guesses = [
        "rock", "paper", "scissors"
    ]
    guessesShortcuts = [
        "r", "p", "s"
    ]
    cmd = input("> ")
    cmd = cmd.lower()
    if cmd == "help":
        print("Help - Opens this menu.\nQuit - Quits and stops the game.\nRPS - Starts a classic game of Rock Paper Scissors.")
    if cmd == "rps" or cmd == "rock paper scissors":
        Guess = str(input(f"Choose your weapon. {guesses[0].capitalize()}, {guesses[1].capitalize()}, or {guesses[2].capitalize()}? "))
        Guess = Guess.lower()
        computerGuess = random.choice(guesses)
        if Guess == guesses[0] or Guess == guesses[1] or Guess == guesses[2]:
            if Guess == computerGuess:
                print("It's a tie!")
                print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
            # Win
            if Guess == guesses[0] or Guess == guessesShortcuts[0] and computerGuess == guesses[2]:
                print(f"{computerGuess.capitalize()}.")
                print("You win!")
                Score += 1
                print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
            if Guess == guesses[1] or Guess == guessesShortcuts[1] and computerGuess == guesses[0]:
                print(f"{computerGuess.capitalize()}.")
                print("You win!")
                Score += 1
                print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
            if Guess == guesses[2] or Guess == guessesShortcuts[2] and computerGuess == guesses[1]:
                print(f"{computerGuess.capitalize()}.")
                print("You win!")
                Score += 1
                print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
            # Lose
            if Guess == guesses[2] or Guess == guessesShortcuts[2] and computerGuess == guesses[0]:
                print(f"{computerGuess.capitalize()}.")
                print("You win!")
                Score += 1
                print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
            if Guess == guesses[0] or Guess == guessesShortcuts[0] and computerGuess == guesses[1]:
                print(f"{computerGuess.capitalize()}.")
                print("You win!")
                Score += 1
                print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
            if Guess == guesses[1] or Guess == guessesShortcuts[1] and computerGuess == guesses[2]:
                print(f"{computerGuess.capitalize()}.")
                print("You win!")
                Score += 1
                print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
        else:
            print("Invalid response.")
```

Comment: Hey, make sure next time you ask a question to say what the problem is. Otherwise people will close your question as "needs more detail".

Comment: You could probably use dictionary to reduce the use of if-else.

Answer (score 1):

In [python](/questions/tagged/python), all `if` statements that are true will execute without regard to the previous `if` statements. What you want to do is have your first statement as an `if` statement, then the rest are elif statements.

Example:

```py
if (condition):
    (code)
elif (condition):
    (code)
elif (condition):
    (code)
...
```

Comment: That might look like the problem at first glance, but the intended `if` conditions are mutually exclusive (and there's no `else`), so the use of `if` is actually fine. The problem is in the conditions.

Comment: I agree @user2357112supportsMonica, but this makes the code organised as well.

Answer (score 1):

`or` has a lower precedence than `and`. When you say `condition1 or condition2 and condition3`, that's treated as `condition1 or (condition2 and condition3)`, and it's true if `condition1` is true, even if the other conditions are false.

When you say

```py
if Guess == guesses[0] or Guess == guessesShortcuts[0] and computerGuess == guesses[2]:
```

that's true if `Guess == guesses[0]`, regardless of what `computerGuess` is.

Also, you don't have any handling for ties if the user enters a 1-letter input, and `guess` is a misleading name for these choices.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python and SO, your problem is already explained by above answers, just use `if-elif-else` and double-check your `condition`

I suggest you should merge 2 `list` into a `dict`. It will make you see it more clear:

```py
rps = {"rock": ['rock', 'r'],
       "paper": ['paper', 'p'],
       "scissor": ['scissor', 's']}
```

About `if` statements, you should consider splitting `condition` into some sub `if-elif-else` statements, it makes your code clearer:

```py
    Guess = str(input(f"Choose your weapon: {list(rps.keys())}? "))
    Guess = Guess.lower()
    computerGuess = random.choice(list(rps.keys()))

    # Rock
    if Guess in rps['rock']:
        print(f"Computer: {computerGuess}")
        if computerScore is 'rock':
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif computerGuess is 'paper':
            print("You lose!")
            computerScore += 1
        else:
            print("You win!")
            Score += 1
        print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
    # Paper
    elif Guess in rps['paper']:
        print(f"Computer: {computerGuess}")
        if computerScore is 'paper':
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif computerGuess is 'scissor':
            print("You lose!")
            computerScore += 1
        else:
            print("You win!")
            Score += 1
        print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
    # Scissor
    elif Guess in rps['scissor']:
        print(f"Computer: {computerGuess}")
        if computerScore is 'scissor':
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif computerGuess is 'rock':
            print("You lose!")
            computerScore += 1
        else:
            print("You win!")
            Score += 1
        print(f"{Score} / {computerScore}")
    else:
        print("Invalid response.")
```

Comment: thank you. i am quite new to Python and am still learning a lot. this response mad ethe mode sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

As @panwen suggested, you can reduce the `if` statement clutter by using a `dict` as a lookup table. Consider using the following to make it easier to find an outcome.

```
solutions = {
    'rock': {'rock': 'tie', 'paper': 'loss', 'scissors': 'win'},
    'paper': {'rock': 'win', 'paper': 'tie', 'scissors': 'loss'},
    'scissors': {'rock': 'loss', 'paper': 'win', 'scissors': 'tie'},
}
```

For example,

```
guess_player = 'rock'
guess_computer = 'scissors'
result = solutions[guess_player][guess_computer]

print(f"It's a {result}. You picked {guess_player} "
      f"and the computer picked {guess_computer}")
```

Answer (score -1):

The while True need some variable in the form
run = True to make the program know when to end the guessing loop by reassigning it a false value at some point or exit like;
run = Tru
while run:
....
....
run = False